# Item not showing in list view after added to database

Tags: android

After I add the items in database they show only after I restart the app. How to fix this? I have tried using `notifyDataSetChanged()` but not sure if i did good.

`Fragment` showing `ListView` and `Button` which calls Add Item Activity:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

    Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewData.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);}});

    listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);

    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper (getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = userDbHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            String nr1, nr2, nr3;
            nr1 = cursor.getString(0);
            nr2 = cursor.getString(1);
            nr3 = cursor.getString(2);
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(nr1, nr2, nr3);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);}
        while (cursor.moveToNext());}
```

Add item Activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.additemactivity);
    number_1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number11);
    number_2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number12);
    number_3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number13);

    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.shtobtn);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number1 = number_1.getText().toString();
            String number2 = number_2.getText().toString();
            String number3 = number_3.getText().toString();

            userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(context);
            sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            userDbHelper.addInformations(number1, number2, number3, sqLiteDatabase);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Data Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            userDbHelper.close();
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();}});
```

List Data Adapter:

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if (row == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.NUMER1=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.number11);
            layoutHandler.NUMER2=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.number12);
            layoutHandler.NUMER3=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.number13);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);}
    else { layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler)row.getTag();}
    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.NUMER1.setText(dataProvider.getNum1());
    layoutHandler.NUMER2.setText(dataProvider.getNum2());
    layoutHandler.NUMER3.setText(dataProvider.getNum3()); return row;
```

Comment: Can you please properly add code here? Because i m not getting which list you inflated in list view ..

Comment: if you used `[Simple]CursorAdapter` + `CursorLoader` all you want would be done automagically

Comment: I inflated a listDataAdapter, its same like every dataAdapter

Comment: @MamataGelanee just posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `listView.notifyDataSetChanged();` after list is updated.

Comment: not helping here, as i said i have used these statement almost everywhere, please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Create one public method in adapter class which is notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLite DB then to automatically populated the updated database values into your list view, you should extend your custom adapter with CursorAdapter. Once you fetch data in cursor it will automatically show you the updated values;

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_list_item, parent, false);
       // return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


    }
 }
```

Comment: added the listdataadapter, have a look

Comment: you need to use CursorAdapter. Like the snippet that i have given above

Comment: in short, using CursorAdapter you need to set your values using a cursor

Answer (score 0):

In your Fragment

```
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
UpdatingReceiver updatingReceiver;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup  container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("some unique key", name);
    String name = "Inside";
}
  @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    String name = "Outside";
    editor.putString("some unique key", name);
    editor.commit();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updatingReceiver = new UpdatingReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("updating receiver unique key");
    registerReceiver(updatingReceiver, intentFilter);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(updatingReceiver);
}
class UpdatingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //list all the data
        //set adapter
        //notifyDataSetChanged
    }
}
```

So you can come to know if you are in inside the fragment or outside the fragment. Based on that you should trigger from your activity.

In your Activity, after you added the code in db just call the receiver based on inside or outside. So it will update immediately.

```
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String prefsString = sharedpreferences.getString("some unique key", "");
if (prefsString=="Inside")
{
   Intent broadCast = new Intent();
                broadCast.setAction("updating receiver unique key");
                sendBroadcast(broadCast);
}
```

Comment: I am using SQLite Database

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```